# User Setting Module at the Top right corner ( Drupal)

Tags: drupal

Is there a Drupal module that allows me to put my user account information at the top right corner?

[http://lh4.ggpht.com/_SDci0Pf3tzU/SexDUQGuhQI/AAAAAAAAEsQ/VzFzR_-CQIQ/s400/user%20logon.png](http://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/do6m0Hz5ffczC8d0rTzwrQ?feat=embedwebsite)

Answer (score 1):

[Logintoboggan](http://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan) has a "Logged in as xyz | Log out" block, but if you can put it in the header depends a bit on the theme you're using.

Also, the [admin menu module](http://drupal.org/project/admin_menu) provides something similar, though only for admins.

Answer (score 0):

Write it yourself... it's not that hard... Just take the hook_block, read it's documentation and implement this in your module. I assume your site has a dedicated module.

For more information read the hook_block documentation here: http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_block

Answer (score 0):

Note that since this is a "look" question, this is best handled at the theme layer:

1. implement hook block to create a block with this information structure as you want it, in your site module, or create a custom block admin/block
2. customize your theme so that is has a region at this location
3. place the block in that region